# Flutter: Cómo se puede crear un botón con borde y esquinas personalizado?

Tags: flutter, dart

Buen día comunidad,

Cómo se puede personalizar un botón?

Adjunto imagen de lo que se quiere:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema que tuve es que no pude agregarle color al fondo, al agregarle el color de fondo este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sé que las esquinas se pueden cortar con el Clip, pero este fue mi resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No está mal, pero si ven no tengo el borde, y al tratar nuevamente de pintar el borde este es el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

No tengo un código aún definido.
Mi pregunta es, cómo harían un botón con ese estilo y que se pueda poner color de Background y color en el borde sin perder el diseño?

Saludos y gracias.

Comment: Es importante agregar lo que trataste o investigaste.

Comment: Custom painter, es la clave